# Precision of double numbers with 17 or more digits

Tags: c, floating-point, double, precision, digits

I am getting precision loss when converting a big double (17+ digits) number to integer.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int n = 20;
    double acum = 1;
    while (n--) acum *= 9;
    printf("%.0f\n", acum);
    printf("%llu\n", (unsigned long long)acum);
    return 0;
}
```

The output of this code is:

```
12157665459056929000
12157665459056928768
```

I can't use unsigned long long for the calculations because this is just a pseudo code and I need the precision on the real code, where divisions are included.

If I increase the decimals the first output becomes, for e.g 12157665459056929000.0000000000.
I've tried round(acum) and trunc(acum) and in both cases the result were the same as the second output. Shouldn't they be equal to the first??

I know float has only 6 decimals precision and double has about 17. But what's wrong with the digits?!?

Comment: @Cornstalks Run his exact code, and you'll see that that site doesn't give the same result he's encountering. Edit: for posterity, since it's been deleted, he linked to http://ideone.com/

Comment: Cornstalks I did but I only get zeros. @Mike Precup what site?

Comment: The site he linked. Can you give us some system information? If that site is giving different results, this may be system dependent.

Comment: Windows plataform + Code::Blocks with GCC compiler here. But i don't think they are related to the issue because I am coding this for a contest and I get Wrong Answer when I send the code using the second output, unlike when using the first one.

Comment: I copied this code and pasted it to http://www.compileonline.com/compile_cpp11_online.php, got the intended solution, i.e., both lines printed were the same.

Comment: @Logicrat true. Something is definetly wrong with my system then. Ty

Comment: nothing wrong with that. Because floating-point types are only exact to the first few digits. 9^20 = 12,157,665,459,056,928,801 which far exceeds long long's precision and you can't represented it correctly by long long either

Comment: The closest IEEE 64-bit binary floating point number to 12,157,665,459,056,928,801 is 12157665459056928768

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, when I change the acum's type to *unsigned long long* like:

`unsigned long long acum = 1;`

the result is:

`12157665459056928801`

When I use Python to calculate the accurate answer:

`>>9**20
 12157665459056928801L`

You see?

`12157665459056929000` is not an accurate answer at all and is actually an approximation of the accurate.

Then I change the code like this:

`printf("%llu\n", (unsigned long long)1.2157665459056929e+019);`

`printf("%llu\n", (unsigned long long)1.2157665459056928e+019);`

`printf("%llu\n", (unsigned long long)1.2157665459056927e+019);`

`printf("%llu\n", (unsigned long long)1.2157665459056926e+019);`

And result is:

`12157665459056928768`

`12157665459056928768`

`12157665459056926720`

`12157665459056926720`

In fact 19 digits is exceeding the numeric digit limit of cpp and the result of converting such a big number is unexpectable and unsafe.

Answer (score 1):

There are several different issues going on here.  The first is
that you are trying to compute 9<sup>20</sup>, which is quite a
big number.  This number requires at least 64 bits to fully
represent, and its accurate value in decimal is 12157665459056928801.
Curiously, that doesn't match *either* of the two numbers your
program printed.  We'll see why in a minute.

All of C's built-in data types have finite precision, meaning
that they can't represent every number perfectly accurately.
Type `double` typically has 53 bits of precision, which works
out to *approximately* 17 decimal digits.  So right away we can
see we're probably going to be in trouble with 9<sup>20</sup>,
which as we saw needs 64 bits or 20 decimal digits.

(An aside: it's easy to get the mistaken impression that "digits
of precision" means "digits to the right of the
decimal point."  But that's not so.  "Digits of precision" means
significant digits *anywhere*.  So for our number
12157665459056928801, we should not expect to be able to
represent all 20 digits of it accurately.  Those last digits
…8801 are going to be on shaky ground.)

In fact, type `double` cannot precisely represent the 64-bit number
12157665459056928801.  The closest it can get is
12157665459056928768, which *looks* like a 64-bit number, but in
fact, it only has 53 *significant* bits, because the last 11 bits
are all 0.  This also means that this number is an exact
multiple of 2048 (which is 2<sup>11</sup>).

(You can't see by looking at it that the low-order bits of
12157665459056928768 are all 0, unless you convert it to
hexadecimal or binary: `0xa8b8b452291fe800` or
`0b1010100010111000101101000101001000101001000111111110100000000000`.
But you'll note that the first 17 digits do match.)

Now, 12157665459056928768 is in fact the second of the two
numbers your program printed.   Your program computed, as a
`double`, the approximation 12157665459056928768 to
9<sup>20</sup>, and then it converted this number to type
`unsigned long long` perfectly accurately, and printed it
perfectly accurately using `%llu` format.  That makes sense.

So where did that other number 12157665459056929000 come from?
I suspect you were using a Microsoft compiler.  Microsoft's
version of `printf` takes an amusing shortcut when printfing
values of type `double`: it computes and prints the first 17
digits, and then it blindly replaces the rest with 0.
(It looks like it did at least round the 17th digit properly.)
This means that it's not computing an exact, full-precision decimal
representation of most `double` values, although it *does* end up
matching (or reinforcing ☹) the easy but mistaken assumption
that "type double has 17 digits of precision".

It turns out it's not easy to compute and print *all* the decimal
digits of a `double` value perfectly accurately — it was
actually an unsolved problem until about 1990 — but other
versions of `printf` (such as those available under MacOS and
Linux) use more-sophisticated techniques and so would have
printed the `double` value of `acum` as 12157665459056928768.